# HPC (mainly on Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, hpc, fortress

I'm looking for some way of using the number-crunching ability of a GPU (with Java perhaps?) in addition to using the multiple cores that the target machine has. I will be working on implementing (at present) the A* Algorithm but in the future I hope to replace it with a Genetic Algorithm of sorts. I've looked at [Project Fortress](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community/) but as I'm building my GUI in JavaFX, I'd prefer not to stray too far from a JVM.

Of course, should no feasible solution be available,  I will migrate to the easiest solution to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parallel Colt](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) might be of interest.

Comment: Does it take implicit parallelism? I'm reading the concurrency section but there doesn't seem to be anything about hardware specific advantages.

Comment: The web page suggests that it will automatically make use of multiple CPU cores where possible. I have not used this version of Colt myself only the original library on which this is based.

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in HPC with GPUs then perhaps you can look [jCuda](http://www.jcuda.de/).  This provides Java bindings for CUDA, along with access to CUDA FFT, CUDA BLAS and CUDA DPP.  I haven't seen any performance reports on this library so I can't guarantee it will be very good.

Beyond that, I'm not really sure.  If you're interested in doing this type of stuff as an educational exercise then Java should be good enough, but if you have a serious need for HPC then you're probably going to want to implement in C and use the Java Native Interface to communicate with it.

Comment: Cheers! I'll take a look at the link ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

Morten Nobel Joergensen has a [blog post](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2010/02/23/real-time-mandelbrot-in-java-%E2%80%93-part-2-jogl/) showing how to create a Mandelbrot Set using [JOGL](http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/pages/Home) - Java Bindings for OpenGL

However if you want generic computing, rather than graphics, then you'd be after the Java bindings for [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/), from which you can chose from [JOCL](http://www.jocl.org/), or [JOCL](http://jogamp.org/jocl/www/) or [JavaCL](http://code.google.com/p/javacl/).

[Wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) shows how OpenCL can be used to compute a fast fourier transform.

Comment: Sweet. In this example he is rendering a 3D image as 2D using a camera with no perspective. Would it be possible to achive raw processing 'umph!' using JOGL then? I ask because I have never used OpenGL before and I don't want to take the plunge unless it will serve my needs.

Comment: Would you have any recommendations on which OpenCL binding to use?

Comment: @Insectatorious - No, so I updated my answer to be more useful.

Comment: @Thorbjørn - No, I've only recently started looking at them myself

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JPPF](http://www.jppf.org/), it is a very nice and mature open source Java grid computing environment